# Appengine folder structure for GO project

Tags: google-app-engine, go

My app works fine using Appengine's development software. When I try to deploy, I get this error:

main.go:11: can't find import: "github.com/afoo/cohort/models"

My folder structure looks like this, where afoo is a subdirectory of a "standard" src/github.com setup, referenced in the GOPATH:

[image: Folder structure]

The app.yaml file is quite simple:

```
application: application-id
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
  - url: /styles
    static_dir: styles

  - url: /scripts
    static_dir: scripts

  - url: /.*
    script: _go_app
```

The main.go file has the URL handler funcs I've defined, for instance:

```
func init() {

    // Register a handler for /.
    http.HandleFunc("/", MapNetworkHandler)
}
```

Module imports in main.go are fully qualified, and look like this:

```
    "github.com/afoo/cohort/models"
```

Google groups has a long discussion from 2014 that attempts to explain the proper folder setup. It's located here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine-go/init/google-appengine-go/dNhqV6PBqVc/Pm2HBrhdCAAJ

From that discussion, I learned that I need to separate all modules (here, models, repository, and utils) from the main folder. But then there are some confusing mentions of other .yaml files that should go into each module folder, with no description of how they look, along with allusions to a skeleton init (.go) file that somehow imports everything else.

For better or worse, I learn by example, and I can't find a good example that would help me. I'd sure appreciate any detailed explanation of the proper folder structures and supplementary files that someone might know about.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For code that is in your project folder use path relative to `app.yaml`.

so if you have:

```
- Folder: MyProject (can be inside GOPATH/github or any other place)
  - app.yaml
  - Folder: MyCode (package mycode)
    - code1.go
    - Folder: MySubCode (package mysubcode)
      - code2.go
```

The imports should be like:

```
import (
  "mycode"
  "mycode/mysubcode"
)
```

Note that you do not specify the github or anything else above the `app.yaml` for code that is is below or on the same level as app.yaml.

*Update*: I keep project folder outside of GOPATH. Like:

```
- ~ (user folder)
  - GOPATH folder
  - My GAE projects folder
     MyProject1
```

This way it works fine with both importing from GOPATH's like "github/*" and from paths relative to app.yaml like "myproject/*"

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. I would prefer to set up the app that way, but I get an error something like "app file xxx.go conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH." According to comments on the Google Groups link in my original post, this error should be solved by "keep[ing] all your yaml files and their associated source files outside of your GOPATH and then import[ing] any other packages you need that are in your GOPATH from those files." That works in the dev environment, but I can't seem to deploy it.

Comment: Try to move your project outside of GOPATH - that's how I do it and it works for me. I'll update the answer with my setup.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. Your solution works, both locally and for uploading. It's interesting, however, that my IDE of choice (VS Code) reports an error on importing my modules:

"Cannot find package 'models' in any of: [GOROOT path] [GOPATH path]"

I'll just leave that be.

Comment: PyCharm works fine. But may be you need to setup project root or add source path somewhere.